# how do i remove a specific object from a array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to remove a specific object with "id":"61d279c1d95e56527e2bdae8" from array of objects.

array would look like,

```
[
{
"id":"61d279c1d95e56527e2bdae8",
"name":"Cushlon Fleece Blanket (Solid, 150cmx230cm) - Dark Grey",
"price":2999,
"quantity":1
},
{
"id":"61ceaf75ebaef7ca9f60c7bb",
"name":"Skin Soft 100 % Cotton Super King Bedsheet With 2 Pillowcases - Pastel",
"productPictures":"i3bxaBh8a-pastel.jpeg",
"description":"sabdsjbfjsd",
"price":899,
"quantity":1
},
]
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you got stuck?

Comment: `array.splice(array.findIndex(i => i.id === '61d279c1d95e56527e2bdae8'), 1);`

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score -2):

it's really simple by using the `filter` higher order function

```
const filteredArray = oldArray.filter(item=> item.id!=="61d279c1d95e56527e2bdae8")
```